# Golang downcasting list of structs

Tags: go

I want to be able to unmarshal yaml files less rigidly. That is, my library has a predefined number of options the yaml file must have. Then, the user should be able to extend this to include any custom options.

Here is what I have

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "yamlcms"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

type Page struct {
    *yamlcms.Page
    Title string
    Date  string
}

func getBlogRoutes() {
    pages := []*Page{}
    yamlcms.ReadDir("html", pages)
}

// This section is a work in progress, I only include it for loose context
func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    //blogRoutes := getBlogRoutes()
    //for _, blogRoute := range *blogRoutes {
    //  router.Handle(blogRoute.Method, blogRoute.Pattern,
    //      func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {})
    //} 
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

Here is the yamlcms package:

```
package yamlcms

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Page struct {
    Slug string `yaml:"slug"`
    File string `yaml:"file"`
}

func (page *Page) ReadFile(file string) (err error) {
    fileContents, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }   

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(fileContents, &page)
    return
}

func isYamlFile(fileInfo os.FileInfo) bool {
    return !fileInfo.IsDir() && strings.HasSuffix(fileInfo.Name(),     ".yaml")
}

func ReadDir(dir string, pages []*Page) (err error) {
    filesInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }   

    for i, fileInfo := range filesInfo {
        if isYamlFile(fileInfo) {
            pages[i].ReadFile(fileInfo.Name())
        }   
    }   

    return
}
```

There is a compiler issue here:

```
src/main.go:19: cannot use pages (type []*Page) as type []*yamlcms.Page in argument to yamlcms.ReadDir
```

My main intent in this question is to learn the idiomatic way of doing this kind of thing in Go. Other 3rd-party solutions may exist but I am not immediately interested in them because I have problems like this frequently in Go having to do with inheritance, etc. So along the lines of what I've presented, how can I best (idiomatically) accomplish what I am going for?

EDIT:

So I've made some changes as suggested. Now I have this:

```
type FileReader interface {
    ReadFile(file string) error
}

func ReadDir(dir string, pages []*FileReader) (err error) {
    filesInfo, err := ioutil.ReadDir(dir)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }   

    for i, fileInfo := range filesInfo {
        if isYamlFile(fileInfo) {
            (*pages[i]).ReadFile(fileInfo.Name())
        }   
    }   

    return
}
```

However, I still get a similar compiler error:

```
src/main.go:19: cannot use pages (type []*Page) as type []*yamlcms.FileReader in argument to yamlcms.ReadDir
```

Even though main.Page should be a FileReader because it embeds yamlcms.Page.

Comment: "I have problems like this frequently in Go having to do with inheritance" -- that's because there is no inheritance in go.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I forgot that slices of interfaces don't work like that. You'd need to allocate a new slice, convert all pages to `FileReaders`, call the function, and convert them back.

Another possible solution is refactoring `yamlcms.ReadDir` to return the contents of the files, so that they could be unmarshaled later:

```
// In yamlcms.
func ReadYAMLFilesInDir(dir string) ([][]byte, error) { ... }

// In client code.
files := yamlcms.ReadYAMLFilesInDir("dir")
for i := range pages {
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(files[i], &pages[i]); err != nil { return err }
}
```

The original answer:

There are no such things as inheritance or casting in Go. Prefer composition and interfaces in your designs. In your case, you can redefine your `yamlcms.ReadDir` to accept an interface, `FileReader`.

```
type FileReader interface {
    ReadFile(file string) error
}
```

Both `yamlcms.Page` and `main.Page` will implement this, as the latter embeds the former.

Comment: I get that, but what I dislike is that both yamlcms.Page and main.Page have to implement the ReadFile function... They will be exactly the same except for the signature.

Comment: @eatonphil: no, they will be the exact same signature except for the type. `Page` implements `FileReader` because it embeds `*yamlcms.Page`.

Comment: @eatonphil that's where you're confused. Because you've embedded `yamlcms.Page` in `main.Page` `main.Page` will be recognized as implementing the interface. You can call ReadFile directly from an instance of `main.Page`. Actually, I would highly recommend against re-implementing that method. Embedding is not inheritance, overriding methods in a type which embeds another would be a very poor design imo. Think of it as composition in traditional OOP but you don't have to reference the thing you compose of, instead it's methods from the embedded type can be invoked directly.

Comment: @JimB I think eatonphil means that in order to unmarshal the additional fields in `main.Page`, they'll need to implement the same method.

Comment: @Ainar-G, so I've made the change but still get a similar error - see my edit.

Comment: @eatonphil I forgot that interfaces and slices don't work like that, sorry. See edit for a possible alternative.